# D3 version 6.1 focus + context + tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am trying to get this code working in version 6, but it didn't work in version 5. Based on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172, version 6 is on https://observablehq.com/@d3/focus-context

I would like to add the points and show a popover. See the image. The points are the white dots, the popover is de Deployment card.
I struggle to get it working, due to:

a. Zoom takes precedence over popover. Can both be combined? If yes, what is the concept? What you see in the image, is the (last) popover working outside the zoom area.

b. Zooming zooms de white dots as well, but not correct. How can I synchronize them.

My code is:

```
options = {
"title":"Ambitie Kennis van Wijkagent - Politie",
"veld":"cumulativekennis","personaid":109,
"ajaxurl":"datablock, see below",
"cockpitassetpad":"apadonserver",
"ankerid":"adpersona"}

datablockajaxurltwoevents =  
[{"persona_id":"109","functienaam":"Wijkagent","starttijdstip":"2019-05-13 00:00:46","tijdstip":"2020-06-13 20:20:46","verstrekentijd":"751931.2500","versnellingsfactor":"5","gebeurtenis_id":"756","samenvatting":"An offender-oriented strategy is necessary","url":"id756-20190620173008.jpg","beschrijving":"A offender-oriented approach is necessary since more and more reports are received from loverboy campaigns. The pressure from local residents and school departments cannot be ignored.","spelrondeactievespelers_id":"135","deltaambitielichaam":"8","profielfactorambitielichaam":"1.172","deltaambitiesamenwerking":"9","profielfactorambitiesamenwerking":"0.923","deltaambitiestatus":"7","profielfactorambitiestatus":"1.143","deltaambitieidentiteit":"8","profielfactorambitieidentiteit":"0.839","deltaambitiekennis":"7","profielfactorambitiekennis":"1.036","deltageldvooraf":"0","deltageldachteraf":"0","deltacapaciteitvooraf":"100","deltacapaciteitachteraf":"80","cumulativelichaam":"59.37600040435791","cumulativesamenwerking":"58.30699980258942","cumulativestatus":"58.00100004673004","cumulativeidentiteit":"56.71199989318848","cumulativekennis":"57.25200009346008","cumulativegeld":"0","cumulativecapaciteitdelta":"180","cumulativecapaciteit":"12535.1875"},{"persona_id":"109","functienaam":"Wijkagent","starttijdstip":"2019-05-13 00:00:46","tijdstip":"2020-06-13 20:30:01","verstrekentijd":"751943.0625","versnellingsfactor":"5","gebeurtenis_id":"764","samenvatting":"Encourage citizen investigation","url":"id764-20190620160813.jpg","beschrijving":"Encourage citizen investigation as a way to use extra capacity to gain extra insight into the phenomenon of loverboys in a certain neighborhood or area.","spelrondeactievespelers_id":"135","deltaambitielichaam":"5.6","profielfactorambitielichaam":"1.172","deltaambitiesamenwerking":"6.4","profielfactorambitiesamenwerking":"0.923","deltaambitiestatus":"5.6","profielfactorambitiestatus":"1.143","deltaambitieidentiteit":"5.6","profielfactorambitieidentiteit":"0.839","deltaambitiekennis":"5.6","profielfactorambitiekennis":"1.036","deltageldvooraf":"0","deltageldachteraf":"0","deltacapaciteitvooraf":"100","deltacapaciteitachteraf":"80","cumulativelichaam":"65.93920057563781","cumulativesamenwerking":"64.2141997502327","cumulativestatus":"64.4017999751091","cumulativeidentiteit":"61.410399738407136","cumulativekennis":"63.05360006942749","cumulativegeld":"0","cumulativecapaciteitdelta":"360","cumulativecapaciteit":"12538.384375"}]

function areaDiagram(options) {
  let kleuren = ["#b5272e", "#0033cc", "#0099ff", "#669900", "#669900"];
  let nl = {
    "dateTime": "%a %e %B %Y %T",
    "date": "%d-%m-%Y",
    "time": "%H:%M:%S",
    "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
    "days": ["zondag", "maandag", "dinsdag", "woensdag", "donderdag", "vrijdag", "zaterdag"],
    "shortDays": ["zo", "ma", "di", "wo", "do", "vr", "za"],
    "months": ["januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"],
    "shortMonths": ["jan", "feb", "mrt", "apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"]
  };
  d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(nl);
  let parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

  let ankerid = "#" + options.ankerid;

  d3.select("#modalHeaderTitle")
    .html("<h4>" + options.title + "</h4>");

  d3.json(options.ajaxurl).then(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.tijdstip);
      d.price = +d[options.veld];
    });

    if (data.length == 0) {
      let svg = d3.select(ankerid)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 72 40")
        .attr("class", "areadiagram"); // was hoogte80
      svg.append('path')
        .attr('d', "M68.1 21.3c-.507-3.14-1.61-6.31-3.25-9.04a6.973 6.973 0 0 1-4.6 4.73c.327.701.611 1.42.859 2.16-1.1.025-2.2.021-3.29-.021-1.74-2.4-5.37-3.7-8.33-1.4-.738-1.59-1.29-3.22-1.59-4.94 1.32.079 2.63.18 3.94.359a6.853 6.853 0 0 1-.591-2.79c0-1.27.344-2.45.941-3.47-2.55-.302-5.12-.391-7.68-.6-1.75-.144-3.09 1.54-3.14 3.14-.151 4.43 1.13 8.56 3.14 12.4-2.01 1.62-3.89 3.07-5.95 4.74-2.62-2.62-5.66-4.88-8.69-6.93-1.58-1.07-3.42-.436-4.76.616-4.11 3.22-8.22 6.45-12.3 9.68-.623.49-1.01 1.04-1.21 1.6h-3.48c-5.07 0-5.07 7.86 0 7.86h29.9c2.38 0 3.82-1.2 4.61-1.88 5.48-4.74 9-7.13 14.5-11.9.129-.11.242-.223.352-.335 2.56.117 5.14.053 7.68-.066 2.19-.096 3.36-1.92 3.03-3.98zM23.4 31.6c1.55-1.22 3.1-2.43 4.64-3.64 1.56 1.11 3.11 2.31 4.5 3.64H43.4z")
        .attr('fill', '#b5272e');
      svg.append('path').attr('d', "M58.4 16.1c3.37 0 6.12-2.74 6.12-6.12 0-3.37-2.74-6.12-6.12-6.12a6.12 6.12 0 1 0 0 12.24z")
        .attr('fill', '#b5272e');
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("y", 5)
        .attr("x", 1)
        .attr("fill", "#b5272e")
        .attr("font-size", 6)
        .text("Nothing to show");
      return;
    }

    let ymin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
      return d.price;
    });
    if (ymin > 0) {
      ymin = 0;
    }
    let ymax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.price;
    });

    let gradientkleur = 0;
    if (data[data.length - 1].price >= 0) {
      gradientkleur = (Math.floor(data[data.length - 1].price / 25) <= 4) ? Math.floor(data[data.length - 1].price / 25) : 4;
    }

    let tooltipdiv;
    if ($("#modal").data("bs.modal").isShown) {
      if (d3.select("#modaltooltip").empty()) {
        d3.select("#modal").append("div")
          .attr("class", "tooltip raster")
          .attr("id", "modalareatooltip")
          .style("opacity", 0);
      }
      tooltipdiv = d3.select("#modalareatooltip");
    } else {
      if (d3.select("#areatooltip").empty()) {
        d3.select("#layout-content").append("div")
          .attr("class", "tooltip raster")
          .attr("id", "areatooltip")
          .style("opacity", 0);
      }
      tooltipdiv = d3.select("#areatooltip");
    }

    let chart = document.getElementById(options.ankerid);

    let dim = {
      window: {
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height(),
      },
      aspectRatio: {
        get screen() {
          return dim.window.width / dim.window.height
        },
        chart: 16 / 9,
        fixed: false,
      },
      modalTitleHeight: 160,
      chart: {
        width: chart.parentElement.clientWidth,
        height: options.height || chart.parentElement.clientWidth * 9 / 16,
      },
      viewBox: {
        x1: 0,
        get x2() {
          return dim.chart.width > 960 ? dim.chart.width : 960
        },
        y1: 0,
        get y2() {
          return dim.chart.height > 540 ? dim.chart.height : 540
        }
      },
      margin: {
        top: 20,
        right: 40,
        bottom: 110,
        left: 70
      },
      margin2: {
        get top() {
          return dim.viewBox.y2 - 70
        },
        right: 10,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 70,
      }
    }

    if (dim.chart.width == 0) {
      dim.chart.width = $(window).width() * .9;
      dim.chart.height = dim.chart.width * 9 / 16;
    }

    if (dim.chart.height > dim.window.height - dim.modalTitleHeight) {
      dim.chart.height = dim.window.height - dim.modalTitleHeight;
      if (dim.aspectRatio.fixed) {
        dim.chart.width = dim.chart.height * dim.aspectRatio.chart;
      }
    }

    let width = dim.viewBox.x2 - dim.margin.left - dim.margin.right,
      height = dim.viewBox.y2 - dim.margin.top - dim.margin.bottom,
      height2 = dim.viewBox.y2 - dim.margin2.top - dim.margin2.bottom;

    dim.chartinner = {
      width: dim.viewBox.x2 - dim.margin.left - dim.margin.right,
      heigth: dim.viewBox.y2 - dim.margin.top - dim.margin.bottom,
      heigth2: dim.viewBox.y2 - dim.margin2.top - dim.margin2.bottom,
    }

    let svg = d3.select(ankerid)
      .style("font", "13px sans-serif")
      .attr("width", dim.chart.width)
      .attr("height", dim.chart.height)
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet")
      .attr('viewBox', dim.viewBox.x1 + " " + dim.viewBox.y1 + " " + dim.viewBox.x2 + " " + dim.viewBox.y2)
      .attr("class", "areadiagram center-block");

    let gradient = svg.append("defs").append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", options.ankerid + "gradient") // geen # toevoegen aan ankerid
      .attr("x2", "0%")
      .attr("y2", "100%");

    gradient.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "0%")
      .attr("stop-color", kleuren[gradientkleur])
      .attr("stop-opacity", 0.75);

    gradient.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "100%")
      .attr("stop-color", kleuren[gradientkleur])
      .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    let x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, dim.chartinner.width]),
      x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, dim.chartinner.width]),
      y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
      y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
      xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
      yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    let brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height2]
      ])
      .on("brush end", brushed);

    let zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
      .translateExtent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height]
      ])
      .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height]
      ])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    let area = d3.area()
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function(d) {
        return y(d.price);
      });

    let area2 = d3.area()
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
      .x(function(d) {
        return x2(d.date);
      })
      .y0(height2)
      .y1(function(d) {
        return y2(d.price);
      });

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", options.ankerid + "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    let focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + dim.margin.left + "," + dim.margin.top + ")");
    let context = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "context")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + dim.margin2.left + "," + dim.margin2.top + ")");

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));
    y.domain([ymin, ymax]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .style("fill", "url(" + ankerid + "gradient)")
      .attr("d", area);

    //  Rect is above circles and so zooming does not work!
    let kring = focus.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data.filter(function(d) {
        return d;
      }))
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.price);
      })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", "1.5")
      .on("mouseover", function(event, d) {
        tooltipdiv.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", 0.95);
        tooltipdiv.html(
            "<div class='card'>" +
            "<img class='card-img-top' src='" +
            options.cockpitassetpad +
            d.url + "'>" +
            "<div class='card-body'>" +
            "<h4 class='card-title'>" + d.samenvatting + "</h4><h5>" +
            d.date.toLocaleString(humhub.config.user.locale, {
              "year": "numeric",
              "month": "long",
              "day": "numeric",
              "minute": "2-digit",
              "hour": "numeric"
            }) +
            "</h5>" +
            "<p class='card-tooltip'>" +
            d.functienaam + ": " + d.beschrijving + "</p>" +
            +d.price.toFixed(1) +
            "</div></div>")
          .style("left", ((event.clientX) + 10) - ((event.clientX > 240) * 240) + "px")
          // .style("top", (event.clientY) + "px");
          .style("top", "1px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(_, d) {
        tooltipdiv.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 1);
      });

    focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

    context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .style("fill", "url(" + ankerid + "gradient)")
      .attr("d", area2);

    context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x.range()); // X is unkown!!

    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + dim.margin.left + "," + dim.margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);

    function brushed(event) {
      if (event.sourceEvent && event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") {
        return;
      } // ignore brush-by-zoom
      let s = event.selection || x2.range();
      x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
      focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
      focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
      svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
        .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
        .translate(-s[0], 0));
    }

    function zoomed(event) {
      if (event.sourceEvent && event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") {
        return;
      } // ignore zoom-by-brush
      let t = event.transform;
      x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
      // How to scale the circles?
      focus.select(".circle").attr("transform", event.transform);
      kring.attr("transform", event.transform);
      focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
      focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
      context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Please show us more of your code. The code you display now has nothing to do with d3-brush, and both links point to the same page for me. It also helps if you focus on one point per question, so people who can answer only one of your questions don't feel hesitant to answer only that part.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot  Updated the question with the complete code. Do you need more information?

Comment: Could you try transforming it into a runnable snippet? If you make a dummy JavaScript object with some data, you can remove the call to `d3.json`. I tried answering your question, but ran into new problems when trying to get zoom to work, while for you it does.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Thanks for your effort. I will try to make a working copy, but it will take some time to figure out how to do it proper.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot I added the options and the data with two events. Is this enough for you?

Comment: Did you know that your `zoomed` function calls your brush and your brush calls your `zoomed` function? It leads to maximum recursion errors

Comment: I stripped a lot from your code, please try to make it a [mre] in the future. Also confirm that it works for yourself first!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes, mostly based on [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-area-chart).

I made `area` and `xaxis` accept both data and an axis scale. This way, you don't have to override `x`, which leads to problems, but you can calculate a new transformed axis `xz` and redraw the area, axis, and circles with it.

I also changed from a `transform` - which is a two-dimensional transformation - to just a one-dimensional re-drawing of `cx`.

To make zoom work, I applied it not to the `rect` you drew, but to the entire `focus` subplot. That also fixed the mouseover I think. At least the tooltip works now.

```js
const options = {
  "title": "Ambitie Kennis van Wijkagent - Politie",
  "veld": "veld",
  "personaid": 109,
  "cockpitassetpad": "apadonserver",
  "ankerid": "adpersona"
}

const data = [{
    tijdstip: "2020-06-14 20:44:00",
    veld: 12
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-14 21:46:00",
    veld: 13
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 20:46:00",
    veld: 14
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 20:48:00",
    veld: 15
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 20:49:00",
    veld: 16
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 20:50:00",
    veld: 17
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 20:55:00",
    veld: 18
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 20:56:00",
    veld: 19
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 20:57:00",
    veld: 18
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 21:03:00",
    veld: 17
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 21:04:00",
    veld: 3
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-15 21:05:00",
    veld: 4
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-16 00:00:00",
    veld: 1
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-16 00:20:00",
    veld: 6
  },
  {
    tijdstip: "2020-06-16 00:25:00",
    veld: 20
  },
];

function areaDiagram(options, data) {
  let kleuren = ["#b5272e", "#0033cc", "#0099ff", "#669900", "#669900"];
  let nl = {
    "dateTime": "%a %e %B %Y %T",
    "date": "%d-%m-%Y",
    "time": "%H:%M:%S",
    "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
    "days": ["zondag", "maandag", "dinsdag", "woensdag", "donderdag", "vrijdag", "zaterdag"],
    "shortDays": ["zo", "ma", "di", "wo", "do", "vr", "za"],
    "months": ["januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"],
    "shortMonths": ["jan", "feb", "mrt", "apr", "mei", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"]
  };
  d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(nl);
  let parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

  let ankerid = "#" + options.ankerid;

  d3.select("#modalHeaderTitle")
    .html("<h4>" + options.title + "</h4>");

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.tijdstip);
    d.price = +d[options.veld];
  });

  if (data.length == 0) {
    let svg = d3.select(ankerid)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 72 40")
      .attr("class", "areadiagram"); // was hoogte80
    svg.append('path')
      .attr('d', "M68.1 21.3c-.507-3.14-1.61-6.31-3.25-9.04a6.973 6.973 0 0 1-4.6 4.73c.327.701.611 1.42.859 2.16-1.1.025-2.2.021-3.29-.021-1.74-2.4-5.37-3.7-8.33-1.4-.738-1.59-1.29-3.22-1.59-4.94 1.32.079 2.63.18 3.94.359a6.853 6.853 0 0 1-.591-2.79c0-1.27.344-2.45.941-3.47-2.55-.302-5.12-.391-7.68-.6-1.75-.144-3.09 1.54-3.14 3.14-.151 4.43 1.13 8.56 3.14 12.4-2.01 1.62-3.89 3.07-5.95 4.74-2.62-2.62-5.66-4.88-8.69-6.93-1.58-1.07-3.42-.436-4.76.616-4.11 3.22-8.22 6.45-12.3 9.68-.623.49-1.01 1.04-1.21 1.6h-3.48c-5.07 0-5.07 7.86 0 7.86h29.9c2.38 0 3.82-1.2 4.61-1.88 5.48-4.74 9-7.13 14.5-11.9.129-.11.242-.223.352-.335 2.56.117 5.14.053 7.68-.066 2.19-.096 3.36-1.92 3.03-3.98zM23.4 31.6c1.55-1.22 3.1-2.43 4.64-3.64 1.56 1.11 3.11 2.31 4.5 3.64H43.4z")
      .attr('fill', '#b5272e');
    svg.append('path').attr('d', "M58.4 16.1c3.37 0 6.12-2.74 6.12-6.12 0-3.37-2.74-6.12-6.12-6.12a6.12 6.12 0 1 0 0 12.24z")
      .attr('fill', '#b5272e');
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("x", 1)
      .attr("fill", "#b5272e")
      .attr("font-size", 6)
      .text("Nothing to show");
    return;
  }

  let ymin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.price;
  });
  if (ymin > 0) {
    ymin = 0;
  }
  let ymax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.price;
  });

  let gradientkleur = 0;
  if (data[data.length - 1].price >= 0) {
    gradientkleur = (Math.floor(data[data.length - 1].price / 25) <= 4) ? Math.floor(data[data.length - 1].price / 25) : 4;
  }

  if (d3.select("#modaltooltip").empty()) {
    d3.select("#modal").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip raster")
      .attr("id", "modalareatooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);
  }
  const tooltipdiv = d3.select("#modalareatooltip");

  let chart = document.getElementById(options.ankerid);

  let dim = {
    window: {
      width: $(window).width(),
      height: $(window).height(),
    },
    aspectRatio: {
      get screen() {
        return dim.window.width / dim.window.height
      },
      chart: 16 / 9,
      fixed: false,
    },
    modalTitleHeight: 160,
    chart: {
      width: chart.parentElement.clientWidth,
      height: options.height || chart.parentElement.clientWidth * 9 / 16,
    },
    viewBox: {
      x1: 0,
      get x2() {
        return dim.chart.width > 960 ? dim.chart.width : 960
      },
      y1: 0,
      get y2() {
        return dim.chart.height > 540 ? dim.chart.height : 540
      }
    },
    margin: {
      top: 20,
      right: 40,
      bottom: 110,
      left: 70
    },
    margin2: {
      get top() {
        return dim.viewBox.y2 - 70
      },
      right: 10,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 70,
    }
  }

  if (dim.chart.width == 0) {
    dim.chart.width = $(window).width() * .9;
    dim.chart.height = dim.chart.width * 9 / 16;
  }

  if (dim.chart.height > dim.window.height - dim.modalTitleHeight) {
    dim.chart.height = dim.window.height - dim.modalTitleHeight;
    if (dim.aspectRatio.fixed) {
      dim.chart.width = dim.chart.height * dim.aspectRatio.chart;
    }
  }

  let width = dim.viewBox.x2 - dim.margin.left - dim.margin.right,
    height = dim.viewBox.y2 - dim.margin.top - dim.margin.bottom;

  dim.chartinner = {
    width: dim.viewBox.x2 - dim.margin.left - dim.margin.right,
    heigth: dim.viewBox.y2 - dim.margin.top - dim.margin.bottom,
  }

  let svg = d3.select(ankerid)
    .style("font", "13px sans-serif")
    .attr("width", dim.chart.width)
    .attr("height", dim.chart.height)
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet")
    .attr('viewBox', dim.viewBox.x1 + " " + dim.viewBox.y1 + " " + dim.viewBox.x2 + " " + dim.viewBox.y2)
    .attr("class", "areadiagram center-block");

  let gradient = svg.append("defs").append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", options.ankerid + "gradient") // geen # toevoegen aan ankerid
    .attr("x2", "0%")
    .attr("y2", "100%");

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", kleuren[gradientkleur])
    .attr("stop-opacity", 0.75);

  gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", kleuren[gradientkleur])
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

  let x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, dim.chartinner.width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  let xAxis = function(g, x) {
    return g.call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  }

  let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

  let zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .translateExtent([
      [0, -Infinity],
      [width, Infinity]
    ])
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  let area = function(d, x) {
    return d3.area()
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function(d) {
        return y(d.price);
      })(d);
  }

  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", options.ankerid + "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  let focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + dim.margin.left + "," + dim.margin.top + ")");

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain([ymin, ymax]);

  focus.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .style("fill", "url(" + ankerid + "gradient)")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return area(d, x);
    });

  //  Rect is above circles and so zooming does not work!
  let kring = focus.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.filter(function(d) {
      return d;
    }))
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.price);
    })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5")
    .on("mouseover", function(event, d) {
      console.log("mouseover");
      tooltipdiv.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0.95);
      tooltipdiv.html(
          "<div class='card'><p>Price: " +
          d.price + '</p><p>Date: ' +
          d.date + '</p></div>')
        .style("left", ((event.clientX) + 10) - ((event.clientX > 240) * 240) + "px")
        // .style("top", (event.clientY) + "px");
        .style("top", "1px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(_, d) {
      console.log("mouseout");
      tooltipdiv.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis, x);

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

  focus.call(zoom);

  function zoomed(event) {
    if (event.sourceEvent && event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") {
      return;
    } // ignore zoom-by-brush
    let xz = event.transform.rescaleX(x);
    // How to scale the circles?
    kring.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xz(d.date);
    });
    focus.select(".area").attr("d", function(d) {
      return area(d, xz);
    });
    focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis, xz);
  }
};

areaDiagram(options, data);
```

```css
svg {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#modalAreatooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.1/d3.js"></script>
<svg id="adpersona"></svg>
<div id="modal">
  <div id="modalHeaderTitle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working now on my site, but ... only if I am above the circles.

Comment: Do you have an idea in which direction I have to search?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, please ask it in a new question if you want